# Handling Alt + Enter key press in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keypress, keyboard-events

I'm trying to get some pure JavaScript code to handle <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press event in a text area but am failing miserably. What is wrong?

### Html

```
<textarea id="ta" style="width:100%;height:500px">
</textarea>
```

### JavaScript

```
var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
ta.onkeypress = function(e) {
   if (e.charCode == 10 && e.altKey){
      alert(
         "Key Pressed: " + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode) + "\n"
          + "charCode: " + e.charCode + "\n"
          + "Alt key pressed: " + e.altKey + "\n"
      );      
   }
};
```

### JSFiddle

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chribben/qqx87vq2/1/)

Comment: Isn't the charCode for enter 13?

Comment: use onkeydown instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution, which is based on [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) in the MDN documentation seems to be the most cross-browser friendly way:

```
var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
ta.onkeydown = function (event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
       return;
    }
    var handled = false;
    if (event.key !== undefined) {
       if (event.key === 'Enter' && event.altKey) {
          alert('Alt + Enter pressed!');
       }
    } else if (event.keyIdentifier !== undefined) {
       if (event.keyIdentifier === "Enter" && event.altKey) {
          alert('Alt + Enter pressed!');
       }

    } else if (event.keyCode !== undefined) {
       if (event.keyCode === 13 && event.altKey) {
          alert('Alt + Enter pressed!');
       }
    }
    if (handled) {
       event.preventDefault();
    };
};
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chribben/qqx87vq2/5/)

Answer (score 6):

`Enter` is key code 13, you need `keydown` or `keyup`, not `keypress` (which is for printable characters), and you should use `keyCode` rather than `charCode`.  Like this:

```
ta.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.altKey) { ...
```

Comment: It works but the `which` property is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which). Using `keyCode` however also works so please update your answer.

Comment: Sorry, seems like `keyCode` is also [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). Gah!

Answer (score 3):

Simple fix: Use the `keyCode` instead of the `charCode`. The keyCode for ENTER is 13.

```
var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
ta.onkeypress = function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.altKey){
      alert(
         "Key Pressed: " + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode) + "\n"
          + "keyCode: " + e.keyCode + "\n"
          + "Alt key pressed: " + e.altKey + "\n"
      );      
   }
};
```

Comment: Did you test that?  It doesn't work for me in Chrome.

Comment: @RichieHindle Interesting. Works in Firefox. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqx87vq2/2/) I assume that it's nonstandard to include the keyCode in keypress events.

Comment: @RichieHindle So actually ALT+Enter do not trigger a keypress event in Chrome, while a keydown event does indeed occur. The differentiation between printable characters and general occurence of key events as stated in your answer seems to be the standardised way, then, while FF is just doing something else, I guess?

Comment: I don't know whether this is strictly specified, but my gut feeling is that Chrome is right - keypress is for printable characters (WM_CHAR in Win32-speak) and keydown/keyup are more general (WM_KEYDOWN / WM_KEYUP).